# Type 'Actionmodel' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to find object in list .

this is my list :

```
export interface Controllermodel {
  controllerDisplayName: string;
  controllerFarsiName: string;
  roleId: number;
  controllerId: string;
  actionsVM: Actionmodel[];
}

export interface Actionmodel {
  displayName: string;
  actionEnglishName: string;
  actionId: number;
}
```

now i need to find object in a list but when i use this code :

```
export class ValidatePermissionDirective implements OnInit {

  show: boolean;
  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
    ,         private dynamic: DynamicPermissionService) { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('appValidatePermission') AccessName:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ValidatePemission();
    if (this.show) {
      this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    }
  }
  ValidatePemission()
  {
    console.log(this.AccessName)
    const find = this.dynamic.dynamicModel.find(x =>
      x.actionsVM.find(z => z.actionEnglishName === this.AccessName));
      console.log(find)
      if (find) {
        console.log(false);
        this.show = false;
      } else {
        console.log(true);
        this.show = true;
      }
  }
}
```

but when i use this code it show me this error :

> Type 'Actionmodel' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

whats the problem ?? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: which line throws the error

Comment: @Sajeetharan in this line : `const find = this.dynamic.dynamicModel.find(x =>
      x.actionsVM.find(z => z.actionEnglishName === this.AccessName));`

Comment: @kianoushdortaj What is the type of `this.AccessName` where do you declare it?

Comment: @MaihanNijat i update the question

Comment: can you please add DynamicPermissionService code also in the question

Comment: @raghulselvam `DynamicPermissionService` just have this model `dynamicModel: Controllermodel[] = [];` and fil that in other serve

Comment: the code looks fine, i believe the problem is where the dynamicModel get filled, if possible can you reproduce this problem in slackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `!!` to ensure that your `find` result is a boolean:

```
const find = this.dynamic.dynamicModel.find(x =>
  !!x.actionsVM.find(z => z.actionEnglishName === this.AccessName));
```

---

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) takes a single parameter: a function that accepts an array element and returns a `boolean`. The returned object will either be the found instance or `undefined`.

```
const find = this.dynamic.dynamicModel.find(
    x => x.actionsVM.find(
        z => z.actionEnglishName === this.AccessName));
```

In the inner `find` call, you have this correct: `z.actionEnglishName === this.AccessName` returns a `boolean`.

In the outer `find` call, you are returning the result of the inner `find`, which will either be an Actionmodel instance or the value `undefined`. These values can be coerced to `true` and `false`, but Typescript wants that to be explicit. By starting with `!!`, you ensure that "truthy" values like an instance will return the value `true`, and "falsy" values like `undefined` will return the value `false`, which matches Typescript's definition of the `find` method.